# How do I add a user in SVN?

Tags: subversion

UPDATE #3:
I think I found it.
/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf

```
<Location /repos>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /var/www/svn/repos
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repos"
        AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

svn-auth-conf is in the format of

```
user1:$apr1$randome letters ... $random letters and numbers
```

I feel like I used some command line tool to add the users but I can't remember what.

UPDATE #2:
locate http.conf gives these results

```
/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logfiles/http.conf
/usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/services/http.conf
```

I don't see anything in either of them that looked related to subversion.  I can post the files here if it will help.

original question:

A few years ago, I installed and setup subversion.  I don't remember how I added a user.  I need to add another now, but when I checked the `passwd` file there were no users defined, nor was there anything set in the `svnserve.conf` file -- both had everything commented out.  That is the only way I can find to add users via google.  So I tried it:

#### passwd

```
user1 = password1
user2 = password2
```

#### svnserve.conf

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
pasword-db = passwd
authz-db - authz
realm = repos
```

but I can still only access it with `user1`, even though `user1` is not a user on the linux server.  Is there some other way to add users or do I have something wrong in my configuration?

update:

I've added the following line to my svnserve.conf file

```
authz-db = authz
```

then my authz file looks like this

authz
    [groups]
    devs = user1,user2

```
[repos:/]
devs = rw
```

still doesn't work.  the password for user1 is different in the passwd than I use to login.  So i think that subversion is not using that for authentication at all.  especially since the file was empty before and I was still able to login.  is there any way to make sure it uses the svnserve,passwd,authz files for authentication?  is there another config file somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subversion authentication typically has two parts. The first is a password repository of some kind. The second is an access control list. The password list is used to authenticate users and check their passwords, but you also have to set which users have access to which resources.

There are several password repository types. I am not familier with the *passwd* type, I use the *htpasswd* type that uses the same user/password files that apache does for user authentication. I add users to this file with `htpasswd .htpasswd username`. It looks like you may have done this step correctly for your password type.

The second part is the ACL. Subversion should have a file called `access` somewhere with sections for each of your repositories. You will need to add a line under the repository you want to access with `username = rw` to give that user read/write access to that repository.

Comment: i'll give it a try when I get home.  that sounds familiar.

Comment: I don't think this is it.  there was no .htpasswd file on my server.

Answer (score 6):

SVN server configuration (mainly) consists of three files:

- authz
- passwd
- svnserve.conf This is the main file (authz-db = authz)

So you just provide us with two config files, please check that the authz file contains:

```
#[the_name_of_repository:/path_in_that_repository]
[test:/]
user1 = rw
user2 = rw
```

for the project **test** you whant to grant access

Comment: I tried this it didn't work.  the password i use to log in as user1 is different than the one i have in the passwd file. so I don't think it is using it at all.

Comment: please, check that you are using the right configuration file: what is the output for `ps aux|grep svn`

Comment: And one more question. How do you get your repos directory structure (svn:// or throught http server)?

Comment: `root   19578   0.0 0.3  4016 664 tty1  R+   05:15   0:00 grep svn`

Comment: through http server

Comment: So, I think Caleb was more closer to the right answer and Arsen7 show you the right way, you have to check (and configure)  http server (not exactly svnserve), but `mod_dav_svn` module of apache. You have to look at [this link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html), please provide us with mod_dav section of your apache config

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: thanks for all of your help.  I marked calebs answer as correct since htpasswd was what I used.  I probably wouldn't have found the password file without your help though.

Comment: `htpasswd passwd username` worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
## Create testuser ##
htpasswd -m /etc/svn-auth-users testuser

New password:

Re-type new password:

Adding password for user testuser2
```

Note: Use exactly same file and path name as used in the `subversion.conf` file. This example uses `/etc/svn-auth-users` file.

Answer (score 2):

```
htpasswd -m /etc/subversion/svn-auth-file yourusername
```

It will then ask for the password and confirm password.

Answer (score 1):

you can use command,

```
sudo htpasswd -cm /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd XXXXX
```

- XXXXX been the user name, then it will ask for the password

this is only if you setup svn with apache, which don't read svn conf folders user name password conf files